# How to set-up this Python data structure in R

Tags: python, r

I have the following data structure in Python that I would like to set-up in R. What is the correct way to achieve this that's most akin to the Python set-up.

```
testing = [
        [[12,14], [4]],
        [[2,1], [5]],
        [[42,11], [13]]
    ]
```

**EDIT 1**

Based on the proposed solution by agstudy using the following code

```
library(rjson)

json_file <- "/Path/JSONdata.json"
json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse=""))
```

Things worked just great. Produced the following:

```
list(list(c(12, 14), 4), list(c(2, 1), 5), list(c(42, 11), 13))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is this? A nested list type structure?

```
ll <- list( c( list(c(12,14)),4) , c(list(c(2,1)),5),c(list(c(42,11)),13))

str( ll )
List of 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : num [1:2] 12 14
  ..$ : num 4
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : num [1:2] 2 1
  ..$ : num 5
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : num [1:2] 42 11
  ..$ : num 13
```

Access elements through `[[` method:

```
#  Second list element of first top-level list element
ll[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 4

#  First list element of third top-level list element
ll[[3]][[1]]
#[1] 42 11
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you don't need quite as many c() functions. Check my edit.

Comment: @jtromans ha ha, yes indeed. Glad you got it sorted and a useful answer from agstudy too.

Comment: Instead of Pat[[3]][[1]], if I want to select Pat[[:]][[1]], how do I achieve this?

Comment: `[[:]]` means all top level elements?

Comment: Yeah I want to select, for example, the first list element of all top-level list elements. I was borrowing the colon notation from Matlab.

Comment: One way would be to use `lapply` like this: `lapply(ll,\`[[\` , 1 )` (I call `Pat`, `ll`!)

Comment: Thanks, and sorry about mixing variable names! lapply(Pat, "[[", 1)  works great.

Comment: @jtromans no problem (and you can escape `\`` in inline code by preceeding the `\`` with a \ ) :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer but maybe a general method to convert structure from python to R. Why not to use an intermediate format to transform your python structure to R structure. for example, through  `json` format.

#### python

```
import json

testing = [
    [[12,14], [4]],
    [[2,1], [5]],
    [[42,11], [13]]
]

with open("testing.json", "w") as file:
json.dump(testing, file)
```

#### R

You use python result like this:

```
library(RJSONIO)
str(fromJSON("testing.json"))
List of 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : num [1:2] 12 14
  ..$ : num 4
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : num [1:2] 2 1
  ..$ : num 5
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : num [1:2] 42 11
  ..$ : num 13
```

Comment: I just tried your code and it works but with `RJSONIO` and not `rjson`. Do you have a specific reason to prefer `rjson` ?

Comment: @dickoa thanks! no particular reason(by the past RJSONIO was faster , but I think `rjson` just catch up). Can you please edit mu answer with your results? (I still do some installations)

Comment: Very nice solution. Thank you very much. Upon import it produces:
list(list(c(12, 14), 4), list(c(2, 1), 5), list(c(42, 11), 13))

Comment: I'm not a fluent pythonista so I don't know if it is the standard way to write `json.dump` to file.